# Angular 6 template driven form & libphonenumber

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm currently working on an Angular 6 template driven form and need to implement format validation for the phone field with country code and flags like this project :

http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/

I know libphonenumber take care of the formatting and parsing of phone number but

I can't seem to find an exemple that uses Angular 6 (or even 5) template driven form. Every demo I found use reactive form or it's for AngularJS...

Is it possible to use libphonenumber with this type of form and if it is how can I use it in my typescript & html files?

ETA :

I've installed 'ngx-intl-tel-input' and added the following:
import {NgxIntlTelInputModule} from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
import {BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

```
 @NgModule({
    imports:  [NgxIntlTelInputModule, BsDropdownModule.forRoot()]
```

I have the code area dropdown but the flags don't appear. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Here's my code for the moment :

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input [(value)]="phone_number" type="tel" maxlength="25" pattern="^[\s0-9]*$" [required]="emailReq ? false : !null"
        [(ngModel)]="phoneReq" name="phone" #phone="ngModel"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Here's the code for the reactive form that I found that uses libphonenumber :

```
    <div formGroupName="country_phone" class="row">
     `enter code here`     <mat-form-field class="full-width col-4">
            <mat-select formControlName="country" placeholder="Country">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
                {{ country.name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width col-8">
            <input matInput placeholder="Phone" type="tel" formControlName="phone" required>
            <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Mobile:</strong> {{ userDetailsForm.value.country_phone.country.sampleMobilePhone }}</mat-hint>
            <mat-hint align="end"><strong>Fixed:</strong> {{ userDetailsForm.value.country_phone.country.sampleFixedPhone }}</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.phone">
              <mat-error class="error-message" class="error-message" 
 *ngIf="userDetailsForm.get('country_phone').get('phone').hasError(validation.type) && (userDetailsForm.get('country_phone').get('phone').dirty || userDetailsForm.get('country_phone').get('phone').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
              </mat-error>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Full Code :
https://github.com/AngularTemplates/angular-forms-and-validations

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself to achieve this? Can you show some code?

Comment: Hello I did. I tried to convert my template driven form into a reactive form but this is not the best solution. I'm new to Angular (and development too) so I'm completely at loss here...That's why I'm looking for an exemple to get started. My phone field only include an input of type tel with a regex which  only accept number...

Comment: The link that you have provided is probably for `angularjs` and not `angular`. Because `ng-model` syntax is in `angularjs`.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote that I only find AngularJS or Angular reactive forms demos. Maybe it's not possible to do it with template driven form?

Comment: It should not be that difficult to convert reactive forms to template forms. Can you give the reference to angular approach using reactive forms to do the same.

Comment: I've edited my post to add the code for the reactive form I was talking about